# PHP - Request Error (invalid request)

Tags: php, codeigniter, internet-explorer-7

A while ago I created a fairly simple CMS using the CodeIgniter framework for a customer.
Over the last couple of months I have had three different users contact me saying they ***sometimes*** get an error when they try an submit data. I have had no reports from other users. The error is:

> Request Error (invalid request)
>   Your request could not be processed. Request could not be handled
>   This could be caused by a misconfiguration, or possibly a malformed request.
>   For assistance, contact your network support team.

I cannot recreate the error on my computer in any web browser. I have tried searching for the same error, but haven't found anything useful. I don't even know if it's a PHP error or browser error (I'm guessing browser).

The customer is using IE7. Users who had the problem and have since upgraded to IE8 are now reporting no problems.

**I would like to know what could be causing this error and if it is something that I can fix or if it is definitely a problem at their end.** I have asked users experiencing this problem to try a different browser or try to recreate it at home, but none have come back to me about this, yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have the users told you what they were doing specifically when receiving this error? If so are all the users experiencing the issue at the same point?

Comment: This problem might be caused by antivirus software (combined with IE7). Are they by any chance using NOD32?

Comment: @Jon Taylor - It seems to be happening when the users submit a form, to add or change something in the database.

Comment: Try turning on Logging via the configuration and set it to 4 (which should be the max logging) and see if any errors are trapped. It's possible that your server is outputting a friendly error instead.

Comment: @Robert Why do you think it might be an Antivirus issue? There seems to be no pattern when this occurs. Is NOD32 known to cause the browser to throw this error?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's "known", but it came up as the cause of this error in a couple of google results.

Comment: Thank you all. I have confirmed with the customer's IT that the problem is solved when the user upgrades to IE8, so it is most probably an *IE7 issue*. I would still like to get to the bottom of it though!

Comment: I've had a similar problem using Codeigniter. Users on IE7 would be logged out and requests wouldn't be processed. The problem was sessions, the useragent on IE7, and at times IE8, would change without notice and therefore forcing CI to destroy that current session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess two things:

1. The form is being sent with method="GET".
2. They are putting in invalid characters, such as `/@$%`.

Make it a POST and you should fix the problem.